# React Native can not connect to Metro

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

i am beginner at React Native.yesterday i wrote a Hello World code then i printed. it's worked.then i tried to update my code just like this:

```
import {View,Text} from "react-native";

function App()
{
  return (<View>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
    <Text>Hello World2</Text>
    </View>)
}

export default App;
```

Now i have error like this:

[Can not connect Metro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwi33.jpg)

[VSC error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cilQb.jpg)

Comment: have you followed exactly what steps are there in RN documentation?

Comment: i followed all this steps: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start your project again. Run npx react-native start, than run npx react-native run-ios

Comment: Ooh . You're right. First i connected to server then i started code. But i wrote npx react-native run-android. Thanks